# Copying XLSX file to GSheet in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to copy over an XLSX sheet to an existing Gsheet, both are in the same GDrive folder. This script works when I run it as `Drive.Files.insert()` but that causes multiple version of the file to be created each time the script is run - so I switched it over to `Drive.Files.update()` like below....

```js
function importXLS(){
  var myFolder= "XXXXXXXXXX"; // Set the folder ID of "FolderB" if you want to copy over to a different folder

  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(myFolder).searchFiles('title = "XXXXX.xlsx"'); 
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var xFile = files.next();
    var name = xFile.getName();
    if (name.indexOf('.xlsx')>-1){ 
      var ID = xFile.getId();
      var xBlob = xFile.getBlob();
      var newFile = {
        title : name + '_converted',
        parents: [{'id': myFolder}],
        supportsAllDrives: true
      };
      file = Drive.Files.update(newFile, xBlob, {  //Originally using Drive.Files.insert() but was creating multiple versions. I want to overwrite the existing version.
        convert: true, supportsAllDrives: true 
      });
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error when this runs...

`Exception: The mediaData parameter only supports Blob types for upload.`

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? This is my first time using Google Apps Script and javascript so I'm kinda flying blind here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have a folder in Google Drive. There are XLSX files and Google Spreadsheets in the folder.
- You want to overwrite the Google Spreadsheet with the XLSX file by searching the filename.

  - Filename of the XLSX file is like `XXXXX.xlsx`.
  - Filename of the Google Spreadsheet file is like `XXXXX.xlsx_converted`.

#### Modification points:

- In the case of `Drive.Files.update`, it is required to include the file ID of the target file.
- In your script, the file ID of the target Spreadsheet is not retrieved.

  - The 2nd argument of `Drive.Files.update` is required to be the file ID. But, your script uses `blob`. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function importXLS() {
  var myFolder = "XXXXXXXXXX"; // Please set the folder ID.
  var filename = "XXXXX.xlsx"; // Please set the filename of XLSX file.

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(myFolder);
  var files = folder.searchFiles(`title="${filename}" and mimeType="${MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL}" and trashed=false`);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var xFile = files.next();
    var name = xFile.getName();
    if (name.indexOf('.xlsx') > -1) {
      var xBlob = xFile.getBlob();
      var spreadsheetFileName = name + '_converted';
      var spreadsheet = folder.searchFiles(`title="${spreadsheetFileName}" and mimeType="${MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}" and trashed=false`);
      if (spreadsheet.hasNext()) {
        Drive.Files.update(null, spreadsheet.next().getId(), xBlob, { convert: true, supportsAllDrives: true });
      } else {
        var newFile = { title: spreadsheetFileName, parents: [{ 'id': myFolder }] };
        file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, { convert: true, supportsAllDrives: true });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the XLSX file of `XXXXX.xlsx` is retrieved from the specific folder. And, Google Spreadsheet of the filename of `XXXXX.xlsx_converted` is searched from the same folder. When the Spreadsheet is found, the Spreadsheet is overwritten by the XLSX file. When the Spreadsheet is not found, a new Spreadsheet is created by converting the XLSX file.

#### Reference:

- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update)

Comment: That did it. Thanks for laying out the modification points, makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @old_dirty_maxer Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.